# $watchCollection triggers - object was not changed but comparison evaluates to non equal

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I am using Restangular to pull data from a webservice.
After that I add a watch to the collection.
This will trigger once and comparing newVal and oldVal also evals to non-equality but even a deep diff shows no difference.

```
var addWatch = function($scope) {
    $scope.$watchCollection('model.organisation', function (newVal, oldVal) {
        if(newVal !== oldVal) {
            console.log("MODEL CHANGE") // ONCE on initialization but I cannot find any difference
        }
    });
};
var OrganisationCrudCtrl = ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$stateParams', 'Restangular', 'StateService', function ($scope, $rootScope, $stateParams, Restangular, S
    var stateRef = StateService.get();
    $scope.model = stateRef; 
    if ($stateParams.slug) {
        Restangular.one('organisation', $stateParams.slug).get().then(function (organisation) {
            // The service stores the object for further use
            StateService.setOrganisation(organisation.data);

            // The watch is added
            addWatch($scope);
        });
    }
}];
```

Comment: so what is the ques? that the watch executes only once?

Comment: It triggers on initialization and catching that by comparing the objects doesn't help because they look equal but javascript evaluates to non equal. I don't want this watch to execute before I change the model myself.

Comment: @DanielKhan do you have a plunker?

Comment: @wickY26 - as this code accesses a local service it is hard to factor this out into a plunker and I think only folks that had this problem before will be able to solve this anyways.

Comment: @DanielKhan I really don't get your requirement here is about $wathc or Restangular? What is your main point...

Comment: @wickY26 - read the title: "$watchCollection triggers - object was not changed but comparison evaluates to non equal"

My thought was that maybe angular adds something to the object - or maybe restangular. 

You add a watch.
You reload the page.
The watch triggers.
You compare the objects: O.K. they really differ
You debug newObject and OldObject and the values are the same.

Comment: @DanielKhan where do you set $scope.modeL.organisation?

Comment: In ´StateService.setOrganisation(organisation.data);´